# CakePHP Migration 3.9 to 4.2 Undefined Method Cake\Core\Plugin::load()

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, migration

I'm migrating CakePHP from version 3.9 to 4.2 and I'm seeing the error:

```
Exception: Call to undefined method Cake\Core\Plugin::load()
```

on the following line in `config/bootstrap_cli.php`

```
Plugin::load('Bake');
```

It seems either `Core` or `Plugin` is not being imported correctly. Earlier in `config/bootstrap_cli.php` I have:

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
```

Perhaps it isn't being installed correctly? My `composer.json` contains the following:

```
    "require": {                                                                                        
        "php": ">=5.4.16",                                                                              
        "cakephp/cakephp": "^4.0",                                                                      
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",                                                          
        "cakephp/migrations": "~3.0",                                                                   
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.0",                                                             
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",                                                                      
        "cakephp/bake": "^2.0",                                                                         
        "cakephp/core": "^4.0"                                                                          
    },
        "autoload": {                                                                                       
        "psr-4": {                                                                                      
            "App\\": "src"                                                                              
        }                                                                                               
    },                                                                                                  
    "autoload-dev": {                                                                                   
        "psr-4": {                                                                                      
            "App\\Test\\": "tests",                                                                     
            "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"                                            
        }                                                                                               
    },                                                                                                  
    "scripts": {                                                                                        
        "post-install-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",                                     
        "post-autoload-dump": "Cake\\Composer\\Installer\\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump"            
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since v4 of CakePHP, there is no such method. You should check for deprecation messages before upgrading: the [code from the last release of v3.9](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.9.5/src/Core/Plugin.php#L110) holds an important message for your problem:

> @deprecated 3.7.0 This method will be removed in 4.0.0. Use Application::addPlugin() instead.